# Ran out of gas while using the browser

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

When I call the function through Remix IDE I have no problem.
But when I try to call it through the browser, I get the error:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

**Sometimes I get the following error in Remix: *Block gas limit exceeded*.**

Code:

```
const smartVotingContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, myContractNumber, {
    from: myAccountNumber,
    gas: '3000000',
    gasLimit: 60000,
    gasPrice: '20000000000'
  });
```

My function in JavaScript:

```
  async function bllt() {
    await smartVotingContract.methods.ballot().call(function (error){
    if (!error) {
      console.log("success")
    }else 
      console.error(error) // error
    });
  }
  
  $("#btn_start_voting").click(function(){
    bllt()
  });
```

My function in Solidity (Remix IDE):

```
 function ballot() public {

        someFunction();
   .
   .
   .

}
```

[image: Deploy and Run transactions (REMIX IDE)]

Answer (score 1):

Please check to make sure your `gaslimit` is not less than your `gas` in `smartVotingContract`. Gaslimit is the maximum amount of gas allowed for your transaction, in order to be executed on the Ethereum blockchain. Block gas limit exceeded means the gas used exceeded your chain's block gas limit (Remix has a default block gasLimit to 3,000,000). To prevent it increase the gasLimit higher than the gas used to deploy your smart contract.

Comment: If I understood I should increase the amount in the "Gas Limit" field in REMIX? As seen in the photo above? And if so, how much should I put in?